# Restore/mirror remote repositories of multiple submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

Since submodules are essentially cloned under .git/modules, the superproject should have all the information it needs to recreate every remote dependency. Is there an easy way to recursively recreate/mirror all these remote dependencies onto a different host from where they were originally hosted?

If the original host of one of these submodule repositories were ever to go down (for whatever reason), I'd like the ability to easily restore the superproject on a new machine.